# Eclipse JavaScript code formatting feature

Tags: javascript, eclipse, code-formatting

I'm using Eclipse for JavaScript and I have a JavaScript project to which I would like to globally apply predefined formatting. If I right click on the project select **Source => Format**, it formats all files except .js files (html, css etc).

I investigated further, and if I right click on specific .js file, Source option is not available.

However, if I open an individual .js file, and press **CTRL+SHIFT+F** the file is formatted correctly.

How can I make it so that when do **Source => Format** in global scope, .js files are included in formatting ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but I just want to say: there are much better editors for JavaScript than Eclipse. WebStorm, Atom, Visual Studio Code, Sublime Text, etc.

Comment: I normally use Atom, but I'm re-evaluating eclipse.

Comment: @MikeC In case if he is a java developer, Eclipse would be better choice because that's the editor we use for editing java files.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala For Java: yes. For everything else: no.

Comment: @MikeC many people do not prefer using 2 editors for the same code base

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala I never said they did. I said that if they're working on a JS project then it's better to use another editor. If you're working on a Java project then use Eclipse.